# Generic HttpHandler vs normal aspx Page HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any difference in using Generic HttpHandler(ashx) instead of normal aspx Page for returning daynamic Images as stream. Every tutorial that I have read about serving dynamic files uses generic handler but I can't seem to find any comparasion article between those two.
Can someone explain why it is good to use Generic handler instead of Page Handler for this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ASPX page is already a generic handler as it implements `IHttpHandler` interface. It's just that it contains lots of code that's absolutely unnecessary when all you need is to generate a dynamic image. So implementing a custom handler will be faster in terms of performance.

Just look at a [typical WebForm page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) (ASPX):

[image]

All this is useless when all you need is to generate a dynamic image. All you care about is the [ProcessRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx) method and write directly to the response stream.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.Bet that the performance jump is really noticable!